# How to iterate and extract data from this specific JSON file example

Tags: python, json, extract

I'm trying to extract data from a JSON file with Python.

Mainly, I want to pull out the date and time from the "Technicals" section, to put that in one column of a dataframe, as well as pulling the "AKG" number and putting that in the 2nd col of the dataframe. Yes, I've looked at similar questions, but this issue is different. Thanks for your help.

A downNdirty example of the JSON file is below:

```
    { 'Meta Data': { '1: etc'
                     '2: etc'},
      'Technicals': { '2017-05-04 12:00': {  'AKG': '64.8645'},
                      '2017-05-04 12:30': {  'AKG': '65.7834'},
                      '2017-05-04 13:00': {  'AKG': '63.2348'}}}
```

As you can see, and what's stumping me, is while the date stays the same  the time advances. 'AKG' never changes, but the number does. Some of the relevant code I've been using is below. I can extract the date and time, but I can't seem to reach the AKG numbers. Note, I don't need the "AKG", just the number.

I'll mention: I'm creating a DataFrame because this will be easier to work with when creating plots with the data...right? I'm open to an array of lists et al, or anything easier, if that will ultimately help me with the plots.

```
    akg_time = []
    akg_akg = []
    technicals = akg_data['Technicals']  #akg_data is the entire json file

    for item in technicals:  #this works
         akg_time.append(item)

    for item in technicals:  #this not so much
         symbol = item.get('AKG')
         akg_akg.append(symbol)

    pp.pprint(akg_akg)
    error: 'str' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've almost got it. You don't even need the second loop. You can append the `akg` value in the first one itself:

```
for key in technicals: # renaming to key because that is a clearer name
     akg_time.append(key)
     akg_akg.append(technicals[key]['AKG'])
```

Your error is because you believe `item` (or `key`) is a dict. It is not. It is just a string, one of the *keys* of the `technicals` dictionary, so you'd actually need to use `symbols = technicals[key].get('AKG')`.

Comment: I knew it was going to be the simplest answer. Thank you. Probably should have just gone to bed and looked it over again tomorrow. The " technicals[key] " was what I was missing the whole time.

Comment: Oh, and thanks for the recommendation on "key" renaming. That does make more sense and is easier to follow the logic of the code.

Comment: @PatrickGalt Glad to help. Don't forget, you can always accept this answer if it helped. Cheers :)

Comment: Could you upvote my question? I'm in "question purgatory" because of some bruised egos...that is, instead of moving-on they decided to bitch and whine over my question (previous one)...which had already been answered pretty effortlessly. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Although Coldspeed answer is right: when you have a dictionary you loop through keys and values like this:

Python 3

```
for key,value in technicals.items():
     akg_time.append(key)
     akg_akg.append(value["akg"])
```

Python 2

```
for key,value in technicals.iteritems():
     akg_time.append(key)
     akg_akg.append(value["akg"])
```

Comment: Remember this is creating a new list in memory, copying all the keys and values, so it is definitely not as efficient as just iterating over the keys.

Comment: Wait now? A dicrionary was assigned here: technicals = akg_data['Technicals']. Would that really create a new list? Makes no sense. What am I missing?

Comment: Just the reference is assigned. It is O(1). I meant `technicals.items()`.